# add condition to join in django orm

Tags: django, django-orm

How to get data equivalent to sql query using django orm:

```
SELECT *
FROM "financeDocuments_documenttemplateline"
LEFT JOIN "financeDocuments_documentinstanceline" ON "financeDocuments_documentinstanceline".template_line_id = "financeDocuments_documenttemplateline".id AND "financeDocuments_documentinstanceline".document_instance_id = 1
WHERE "financeDocuments_documenttemplateline".document_type_id = 1
```

I use:

```
document_lines = DocumentTemplateLine.objects.filter(document_type__id = document_instance.document_type.id).select_related('documentinstanceline').values('documentinstanceline__value')
```

But it generates:

```
SELECT "financeDocuments_documentinstanceline"."value" FROM "financeDocuments_documenttemplateline" LEFT OUTER JOIN "financeDocuments_documentinstanceline" ON ("financeDocuments_documenttemplateline"."id" = "financeDocuments_documentinstanceline"."template_line_id") WHERE "financeDocuments_documenttemplateline"."document_type_id" = 1
```

Models are like this one:

```
class DocumentInstance(models.Model):
    company        = models.ForeignKey(Company)
    period         = models.ForeignKey(Period,       verbose_name=u'период')
    document_type  = models.ForeignKey(DocumentType, verbose_name=u'вид документа' )
    created        = models.DateTimeField('created', auto_now_add=True)
    author         = models.ForeignKey(User)

    class Meta:
        unique_together= (('company', 'period', 'document_type'),)



class DocumentInstanceLine(models.Model):
    document_instance = models.ForeignKey(DocumentInstance, related_name='lines')
    template_line     = models.ForeignKey(DocumentTemplateLine)
    value             = models.FloatField(default=0.00)
    comment           = models.TextField(blank=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together= (('document_instance', 'template_line'),)
```

How to change code for django orm to add second condition like in my first sql query?

Comment: If you need something specific you may need a custom `Manager` class. Could you please post your models to get a better idea of what you're trying to do?